# Outputting user status' from a database, but occationally output a users profile picture instead

Tags: php, sql, database, while-loop

My website pulls out user status updates one after another.

**[status] [status] [status] [status] [status] [status] [status] [status]**

But I would like it to sometimes output a users profile image instead, but not in a uniform way, more of a random way. So, sometimes like this:

**[status] [status] [picture] [status] [status] [status] [status] [picture]**

and other times maybe like this:

**[picture] [picture] [status] [status] [picture] [status] [status]**

I'm not sure how to achieve this, here's how my code is currently looking:

```
    $result = mysql_query(
                "SELECT 

                tbl_status.id as statID, 
                tbl_status.from_user as statFROM, 
                tbl_status.status as statSTATUS, 
                tbl_status.deleted as statDEL, 
                tbl_status.date as statDATE,

                tbl_users.id as usrID, 
                tbl_users.name as usrNAME,
                tbl_users.location as usrLOCATION,
                tbl_users.postcode as usrPOSTCODE,

                tbl_photos.profile as photosPROFILE,
                tbl_photos.photo_link as photoLINK,
                tbl_photos.default_photo as photoDEFAULT 

                FROM tbl_status 
                LEFT JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id

                LEFT JOIN tbl_photos ON tbl_photos.profile = tbl_users.id 
                WHERE tbl_status.deleted = '0' AND tbl_photos.default_photo IS NULL OR tbl_photos.default_photo = '1'
                ORDER BY tbl_status.date desc
                LIMIT 100

                ");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {echo' <div class="statusUsr">' . $row['statSTATUS'] . '</div>'}
```

Comment: When outputting image do you also want to output the status related to that record in addition to the image (i.e. do you randomly show both) or is the image to be in place of the status (i.e. randomly show one or the other)?  BTW, either of these is pretty trivial to implement.  I would have expected you could show what you are currently attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php's rand function to show randomly the status or the photo:

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){        

        $rand = rand(1,2); // get a random number between 1 and 2

        if($rand%2 == 0) { // check if the random number is odd or even 

            // case 2
            echo' <div class="statusUsr">' . $row['statSTATUS'] . '</div>';
        } else {

            // case 1
            echo' <div class="imageUsr">' . $row['photoLINK'] . '</div>';
        }
  }
```

References:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: This sounds like the right answer. Would this still eventually output all status' still or miss them out in place of images? - Also, what if there were no images left to put, would there be an error?

Comment: Like Bob Ross said: you can do what you want. Currently it is shown the status OR the image. But you can simply show the image additionaly. There is no check for a valid image url like you can see.

Comment: this one will just alternate between user statut and user image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will have "more" randomness with that.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $nb = rand()%100; // get a random number from 0 to 100

    if ($nb&1) // check if it's odd or even
       echo' <div class="statusUsr">' . $row['statSTATUS'] . '</div>';
    else
       echo' <div class="imageUsr">' . $row['photoLINK'] . '</div>';
}
```